# Grub2 in Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't add “quiet splash” to Fedora kernel

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

Grub2 installed in Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't add `quiet splash` kernel parameters to Fedora's kernel.

Here are the options in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Info page has this information:

> ‘`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`’
>
> Command-line arguments to add to menu entries for the Linux kernel.
>
> ‘`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`’
>
> Unless ‘`GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY`’ is set to ‘true’, two menu entries will be generated for each Linux kernel: one default entry and one entry for recovery mode. This option lists command-line arguments to add only to the default menu entry, after those listed in ‘`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`’.

According to this, present settings in `/etc/default/grub` should result in `quiet splash` kernel parameters for Fedora too. But it doesn't. While the Ubuntu's kernel gets `ro quiet splash` as kernel parameters.

If I set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"`, then fedora's kernel gets the parameters.

Why is this happening? Should I edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX variables are used by 10_linux to create menuentry for Ubuntu's kernel and recovery image.

On the other hand, menuentry for Fedora is created by 30_os-prober. It doesn't use variables defined in /etc/default/grub to create arguments.

Manually adding arguments in /boot/grub/grub.cfg doesn't work.

I just remembered that I had solved the same problem when I was in college by editing 30_os-prober.

Thanks and have a happy new year.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is strange, I just tested and the parameters added to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` get added to each kernel I have installed on my Debian. As far as I can tell, this should work.

In any case, if adding the options to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` works, you may as well do it that way. You can also edit `grub.cfg` manually, just remember that your changes will be overwritten if you update.